# Installing a custom grafana datasource through helm / terraform

Tags: terraform, datasource, kubernetes-helm, grafana, kube-prometheus-stack

I would like to install the alertmanager datasource (https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/camptocamp-prometheus-alertmanager-datasource/) to my `kube-prometheus-stack` installation which is being built using terraform and the helm provider.  I cannot work out how to get the plugin files to the node running grafana though.

Using a modified `values.yaml` and feeding to `helm` with `-f values.yaml` (please ignore values):

```
  additionalDataSources:
  - name: Alertmanager
    editable: false
    type: camptocamp-prometheus-alertmanager-datasource
    url: http://localhost:9093
    version: 1
    access: default
    # optionally
    basicAuth: false
    basicAuthUser:
    basicAuthPassword:
```

I can see the datasource in grafana but the plugin files do not exist.

[Alertmanager visible in list of datasources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JycJ.png)

However, clicking on the datasource I see

[Plugin not found, no installed plugin with that ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QESG.png)

**Please note** that the grafana pod seems to require a restart to pick up datasource changes as well which I would consider needs fixing at a higher level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually quite simple to get the files there and I cannot believe I overlooked the simplistic solution.  Posting this here in the hope others find it useful.

In the `kube-prometheus-stack`, `values.yaml` file, just override the grafana section as follows:

```
grafana:
  .
  .
  .
  plugins:
    - camptocamp-prometheus-alertmanager-datasource
    - grafana-googlesheets-datasource
    - doitintl-bigquery-datasource
    - redis-datasource
    - xginn8-pagerduty-datasource
    - marcusolsson-json-datasource
    - grafana-kubernetes-app
    - yesoreyeram-boomtable-panel
    - savantly-heatmap-panel
    - bessler-pictureit-panel
    - grafana-polystat-panel
    - dalvany-image-panel
    - michaeldmoore-multistat-panel

  additionalDataSources:
  - name: Alertmanager
    editable: false
    type: camptocamp-prometheus-alertmanager-datasource
    url: http://prometheus-kube-prometheus-alertmanager.monitoring:9093
    version: 1
    access: default
    # optionally
    basicAuth: false
    basicAuthUser:
    basicAuthPassword:
```

where the name / type of the plugin can be found on the installation instructions on the [Grafana Plugins page](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins)

Comment: Thank you for this I was banging my head against a wall because I didn't include it in both plugins and datasources!

Answer (score 0):

I made some progress by discovering I could get onto the pod running grafana using:

- `kubectl exec -it --container grafana  prometheus-grafana-5d844b67c6-5p46b -- /bin/sh`

The one listed in `kubectl get pods` was the sidecar.

Then I could run:

- `kubectl exec -it --container grafana  prometheus-grafana-5d844b67c6-5p46b -- grafana-cli plugins install camptocamp-prometheus-alertmanager-datasource`

which did the required file installation.  After deleting and recreating the pod, there is progress

Keen to hear any comments on the approach or better ideas!